# MySql not Connecting to Java

Tags: java, mysql

So this is my connection statements:

```
    try {
        
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "blasphemy3k";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        
        Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select *from *students ";
        ResultSet rs = ((java.sql.Statement) st).executeQuery(sql);
        
        while(rs.next()) {
            
            String id = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("id"));
            String name = rs.getString(rs.getInt("name"));
            
            String tbData[] = {id,name};
            DefaultTableModel tblModel = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
            
            tblModel.addRow(tbData);
            
        }
```

When I run this code the compiler this message is shown also the jTable1 doesnt show any data from students table from usersdb

```
   class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl cannot be cast to class 
   com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl and 
   com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement are in module mysql.connector.java@8.0.29 of loader 'app')
```

Comment: A big rule in Java is that if you are casting, then you are probably doing it wrong.  Why are you casting? Fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post imports of this java file?

Seems you import a wrong `Statement` class whose full name is **`com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement`**, the right one should be **`java.sql.Statement`**.

I do not know which version of `mysql-connetor-j` you are using, this is what I found with version 8.0. `StatementImpl` implements `JdbcStatement`, and `JdbcStatement` implements **`java.sql.Statement`** (rather than **`com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement`**, shows in the figures below).

So if you want to cast `StatementImpl` to `Statement`, this should work:

```java
java.sql.Statement st = (java.sql.Statement) con.createStatement();
```

[image: StatementImpl]
[image: JdbcStatement]

[StatementImpl code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release%2F8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/StatementImpl.java)
[JdbcStatement code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-api/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/JdbcStatement.java)

Comment: here are the imports @SteveHu import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.*;  

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

Comment: @freepremium okay，that make sense. Seems the wrong Statement class is imported. Have a try on this: replace this line ‘import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.Statement’ with ‘import java.sql.Statement’